# Multiple select from list + with multiple values

Tags: android, select, spinner

I'm dynamically generating list of Books where the user can select more than one Book to buy.I want to have multiple select.Every List Item will have 2 TextView(Title of the book & Author),1 Spinner and check list. Spinner is it order multiple copies.Any help will be  much appreciated!

Comment: What's your question? That is, which part(s) of this do you need help with?

Comment: I am able to display 2TextView and Checkbox but not able to bring the spinner into List item..As Spinner is null all the time..I have no Idea why Spinner is null all the time. The spinner code works perfectly individually .

Comment: Please post a code snippet of what you have right now.

Answer (score -1):

class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
IconicAdapter() {
super(FoodItems.this, R.layout.order_items_check, items);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_items_check, parent, false);
TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.bookname);
label.setText(items[position]);
TextView price=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.author);
price.setText("$"+prices[position]);
String array_spinner[]={"1","2","3","4","5"};;
// Here is the problem 's' is always null hence s.setAdapter throws exception

```
  Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner10);
   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(FoodItems.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

//Till here
final CheckBox check=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);
final String foodid = foodIds[position];
if(CheckedItems.checkedItems.contains(foodid))
check.setChecked(true);
else
check.setChecked(false);
label.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent myIntent;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("foodid", foodid);
myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemView.class);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(check.isChecked())
{
if(CheckedItems.checkedItems.contains(foodid)==false){
      CheckedItems.checkedItems.addElement(foodid);
}
}
else
{
if(CheckedItems.checkedItems.contains(foodid))
CheckedItems.checkedItems.removeElement(foodid);
}
}
});
return(row);
}
}